# Collapse arrow on mouse click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this example of Collapse row on mouse click:

```
jsfiddle.net/7bz5au97/
```

I would like to ask you how I can add arrow like this one at the beginning of the question and rotate it when the question is expanded?

[image]

Can this be done with CSS only or I need also to add JavaScript?

Comment: It depends, is the HTML exactly the one you have in jsfidlle or are you going to write a new one?

Comment: It's the same. I will just change the content.

Comment: Also, do you actually want to rotate the image during the expand toggle animation or just switch it out with the opposite state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this almost entirely with css:

```js
var arr = document.querySelector('.arrow');
arr.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('down');
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  margin: 1em;
}

.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: gray;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform .25s;
}

.arrow.down::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform .25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: I could, but then what would we need you for?

Comment: I updated the code this way but it's not working properly http://jsfiddle.net/2acub4x6/

Comment: What is this wizardry? How on earth does it result in a triangle shape? BTW I don't think position absolute makes it terribly usable

Comment: @StefanReich It's a triangle because borders meet at 45° at the corners. Picture a square with an ✕ through it. That's where the top/right/bottom/left borders meet for an element with zero height and width. If you make the left border grey and the rest transparent, it's like filling in the left quadrant of the ✕, and you get a triangle. It has to be position absolute for it to rotate independently, etc., and it's a pseudo-element anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update of your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7bz5au97/1/

I just added

```
$('body').click(function() {
$( 'img' ).toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

and rotate to the img

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I want!

Comment: Can you show me how I can replace the image with pure CSS code, please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7bz5au97/2/  just change the img with a div and I put a background-image on it

Comment: I mean completely to remove the image and replace it with CSS made image.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, you can try to do this yourself or ask an other question

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple triangle using CSS but it gets complicated if you want rounded corners like in your image.

More fancy CSS shapes [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

```js
$(function () {
    $('span').click (function () {
        $(this).toggleClass ('expanded');
        $('p').toggleClass ('expanded');
    });
});
```

```css
p:not(.expanded) {
    display:none;
}

span {
    display:block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid black;
}

span.expanded {
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Is that really necessary? Your fiddle already demonstrates experience with jQuery. All it takes is a couple copy pastes and minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here's a version of it that doesn't require javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/6xnptkLg/

```css
.single-row input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.intro {
    display. block;
}

.intro .fa {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.opener:checked+label .content {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100px;
}

.opener:checked+label .intro .fa {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="single-row">
    <input name="collapsable" type="radio" id="col-1" class="opener" />
    <label for="col-1">
        <span class="intro">Intro1<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Some text down here
            </p>
        </div>
    </label>    
</div>

<div class="single-row">
    <input name="collapsable" type="radio" id="col-2" class="opener" />
    <label for="col-2">
        <span class="intro">Intro2<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Some text down here
            </p>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="single-row">
    <input name="collapsable" type="radio" id="col-3" class="opener" />
    <label for="col-3">
        <span class="intro">Intro3<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Some text down here
            </p>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Simple CSS Only Solution without Images

Requirement:
*"I would like to ask you how I can add arrow like this one at the beginning of the question and rotate it when the question is expanded?"*

For simple popup information like this, one could just do it all with CSS ... without any scripting.  And unicode arrows ▶ would work in place of loading images and doing image transforms. I'm just tossing this in as one alternative.

**Run the Snippet to Test**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
ul {
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
li::before {
 content: "▶ ";
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
li:hover::before {
 content: "▼ ";
 color: red;
}
li > div {
 margin: 0.5em;
 display: none;
}
li:hover > div {
 display: block;
 height: 5em;
 width: 20em;
 border: 1px gray dotted;
 padding: 1em;
 background-color: ghostwhite;
}
</style>
<b>Example</b>
<ul>
<li>Q1: Can I try the software before I buy it?
<div>
 Yes! Simply download a free trial and you'll have 
 instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely 
 free. We don't require your credit card details or any 
 commitment.
</div>
<li>Q2: Can I try the software before I buy it?
<div>
 Yes! Simply download a free trial and you'll have 
 instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely 
 free. We don't require your credit card details or any 
 commitment.
</div>
<li>Q3: Can I try the software before I buy it?
<div>
 Yes! Simply download a free trial and you'll have 
 instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely 
 free. We don't require your credit card details or any 
 commitment.
</div>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```